# Adding views to tableViewCell contentView on xib?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a `xib` file that is setup as a custom `UITableViewCell` class. This xib is simple and just has a UILabel inside of it with constraints binding it to the superview. I am utilizing [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout#comments) tutorial to implement dynamic cell height. Everything should be working, but by using a `xib` all of the views I add are not added as subviews of the content view, but the cell itself. This is creating an issue with `autolayout`. The dynamic resizing is dependent upon using the contentView of the cell to determine the required height.

How can I add a view to a xib that will be a subview of the cells `contentView` and not the cell itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ended up being an overlook on my part. I had created the cell using the default view that xib's are initially setup with. I needed to drag out a UITableViewCell view from the object library and add my labels etc. to the content view of that cell.

Comment: I just did exactly that... thanks for posting this, it was getting frustrating :)